# How to make constructors that create default values for the parametrically typed fields

Tags: types, constructor, julia, default-value, parametric-polymorphism

For a type with parametrically typed fields like:

```
struct Point{T <: AbstractFloat}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

How to make an outer constructor that creates default values with the desired types? For example, I want `Point()` which takes no arguments to create `Point{T}(0.0, 0.0)`, where I can still specify `T` as `Float64` or other types by some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
julia> struct Point{T <: AbstractFloat}
           x::T
           y::T
       end

julia> Point{T}() where T = Point{T}(zero(T), zero(T))

julia> Point{Float64}()
Point{Float64}(0.0, 0.0)

julia> Point{Float32}()
Point{Float32}(0.0f0, 0.0f0)

julia> Point{Float16}()
Point{Float16}(Float16(0.0), Float16(0.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding an additional dependency, the package `Parameters.jl` provides the macro `@with_kw` allowing to specify default values in the following way:

```
using Parameters
@with_kw struct Point{T <: AbstractFloat}
  x::T = 0.0
  y::T = 0.0
end

julia> Point()
Point{Float64}
  x: Float64 0.0
  y: Float64 0.0

julia> Point{Float32}() 
Point{Float32}
  x: Float32 0.0f0
  y: Float32 0.0f0
```